# Memory usage: nil interface{} vs struct{}

Tags: go, memory-management

I'm trying to learn more regarding memory usage.

Doing some tests with `interface{}` and `struct{}` slices, I noticed that a slice of `struct{}` doesn't allocate any memory whereas a slice of `interface{}` does. It doesn't make so much sense to me, I'm actually expecting the same behavior (ie. both allocate nothing). Anyway I couldn't find any explanation regarding this particular case.

Could someone explain me why this happens?

```golang
package main

import (
    "runtime"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    // Below is an example of using our PrintMemUsage() function
    // Print our starting memory usage (should be around 0mb)
    fmt.Println("Start")
    PrintMemUsage()
    fmt.Println("")

    structContainer := make([]struct{}, 1000000)
    for i := 0; i<1000000; i++ {
    structContainer[i] = struct{}{}
    }

    fmt.Println("With 1kk struct{}")
    PrintMemUsage()
    fmt.Println("")

    nilContainer := make([]interface{}, 1000000)
    for i := 0; i<1000000; i++ {
    nilContainer[i] = nil
    }

    fmt.Println("With 1kk nil interface{}")
    PrintMemUsage()
    fmt.Println("")
}

// PrintMemUsage outputs the current, total and OS memory being used. As well as the number 
// of garage collection cycles completed.
func PrintMemUsage() {
        var m runtime.MemStats
        runtime.ReadMemStats(&m)
        // For info on each, see: https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#MemStats
        fmt.Printf("Alloc = %v KiB", bToMb(m.Alloc))
        fmt.Printf("\tTotalAlloc = %v KiB", bToMb(m.TotalAlloc))
        fmt.Printf("\tSys = %v KiB", bToMb(m.Sys))
        fmt.Printf("\tNumGC = %v\n", m.NumGC)
}

func bToMb(b uint64) uint64 {
    return b / 1024
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/t_jko-1nxlR).

Comment: `nil` isn’t a type, you’re comparing `struct{}` and `interface{}`

Comment: Your code contains no arrays at all. These are slices. There is a special rule for `struct{}`: See the last two sentences of https://golang.org/ref/spec

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A variable of type `interface{}` can hold any value. E.g. it can hold the integer `8`, it can hold the `string` value `"hi"`, it can hold the struct value `image.Point{X: 1, Y: 2}` and pretty much everything else.

If you allocate a slice having `interface{}` as its element type, memory have to be allocated so that you can store any values in its elements. When using `make()` to allocate it, all its elements will get the zero value of the element type (which is `nil` for the `interface{}`), but memory still has to be allocated else you couldn't set elements later on.

On the other hand, the empty struct `struct{}` has no fields, it cannot hold any values (other than `struct{}`). When you allocate a slice having `struct{}` as its element type, memory does not need to be allocated because you won't be able to store anything in it that would require memory. So it's a simple and clever optimization not to allocate memory for such a type.

Answer (score 2):

This is because an empty struct contains no value.

This is not very useful for arrays or slices. But it is useful for maps. A  map without value is like a set. You can insert keys and test if they are present. The absence of value save space as you discovered.